# Axios and looped promises

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, axios

I have problem with loop on axis GET request, and I can't understood why.

```
const [ state, setState ] = useState<any[]>([]);

ids.forEach((id) => {
    getData(id)
        .then((smth: Map<string, any>[]) => getNeededData(smth, id));
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
```

and getData (getNeededData is only choose parameters):

```
export const getData= async (id: string) => {
const response = await Axios.get(`/rest/${id}`)
    .then((res: { data: any; }) => res.data);
return response;
};
```

I should have 2 response (it's 2 id in variable "ids"), but I have first, second, first, second, first, and this in a loop.
Why it's been working like this?
What I can change for fix this?

Comment: Do you want these requests to execute serially or in parallel?

Comment: It's max 5 request so it isn't a big difference, but I'am curious, how to change between serially and parallel? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting that `forEach` at the top level of your component function, you're running it **every time** the function is called by React to render its contents, which React does when state changes. The code you've shown doesn't set state, but I'm assuming your real code does.

To do it only when the component first mounts, wrap it in a `useEffect` callback with an empty dependency array:

```
const [ state, setState ] = useState<any[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    ids.forEach((id) => {
        getData(id)
            .then(/*...*/);
    });
}, []);
```

If all of the results are going in the `state` array, you probably want to use `map` and `Promise.all` to gether them all up and do a single state change with them, for instance:

```
const [ state, setState ] = useState<any[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all(
        ids.map((id) => {
            return getData(id).then(/*...*/);
        })
    )
    .then(allResults => {
        // Use `allResults` to set state; it will be an array in the same order
        // that the `id` array was in
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // handle/report error
    });
}, []);
```